# Calling one method from another in JS

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework, javascript-objects

I have the following snippet of JS

```
var Customer : function()
{
    this.ShipProduct : function()
    {
       //Logic for shipping product. If shipping successful, notify user
       //Here I am trying to call Notify
       //this.Notify(); // does not work
    }

    this.Notify = function()
    {
      //Logic for notify
    }
}
```

How would I call Notify from ShipProduct?

Comment: Can you try by just moving the method notify above the ShipProduct method ?

Comment: @In Sane - No, that doesn't work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is not JS, that is a collection of syntax errors.

Use `=` when assigning variables, and `:` inside simple objects, don't confuse simple objects and functions, don't forget commas, and don't prefix property names with `this.`.

```
var Customer = {
    ShipProduct : function()
    {
       //Logic for shipping product. If shipping successful, notify user
       //Here I am trying to call Notify
       this.Notify(); // this does work
    },
    Notify: function()
    {
      //Logic for notify
    }
}

Customer.ShipProduct();
```

Comment: I am not creating a one off object. I'd like to create multiple instances of this object and my understanding is that the syntax you have used creates an associate array of functions. I'd like to do something like var customer = new Customer();

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type = "text/javascript" language = "JavaScript">
var Customer = function(){
    this.ShipProduct = function(){
        alert("hey!");
        this.Notify();
    };

    this.Notify = function(){
      //Logic for notify
        alert("notify");
    };
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script type = "text/javascript" language = "JavaScript">
var cust = new Customer();
cust.ShipProduct();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This example looks fine except for the first line, that colon should be an equal sign.

The problem, I'm guessing, has to do with how you're calling `ShipProduct`. If you're doing it like this, everything should work:

```
var customer = new Customer();
customer.ShipProduct();
```

However if you **detach** the method and call it directly, it won't work. Such as:

```
var customer = new Customer();
var shipMethod = customer.ShipProduct;
shipMethod();
```

This is because JavaScript relies on the dot notation accessor to *bind* `this`. I'm guessing that you're passing the method around, perhaps to an Ajax callback or something.

What you need to do in that case it wrap it in a function. Such as:

```
var customer = new Customer();
var shipMethod = function() {
    customer.shipMethod();
};
... later, in some other context ...
shipMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
var Customer = function() {
    var notify = function() {
        ...
    };
    var shipProduct = function() {
        ...
        notify(...);
        ...
    };
    return {
        notify: notify,
        shipProduct: shipProduct
    };
}
```

This assumes that you want to expose both functions -- if `notify` is only used by `Customer` internally, then there's no need to expose it, so you would instead return like so:

```
    return {
        shipProduct: shipProduct
    };
```